# How do you get FFmpeg script -hwaccel overlay_cuda to fade in and out an image?

Tags: ffmpeg, cuda, overlay

The following FFmpeg hardware-acceleration script works fine. But when I try to apply a fade in and out to the overlayed image it breaks. Is there a solution?

Working:
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i vidTest.mp4 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i imgTest.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale_npp=960:540:format=yuv420p,hwdownload,hwupload_cuda,scale_npp=format=nv12[base];[1:v]scale_npp=470:-1:format=nv12[A];[base][A]overlay_cuda=515:80" -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -y outTest.mp4

Breaks:
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i vidTest.mp4 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i imgTest.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale_npp=960:540:format=yuv420p,hwdownload,hwupload_cuda,scale_npp=format=nv12[base];[1:v]scale_npp=470:-1,fade=st=0:d=2:alpha=1,fade=out:st=9:d=2:alpha=1,trim=0:15,setpts=PTS+4/TB,format=nv12[A];[base][A]overlay_cuda=515:80:enable='between(t,4,15)'" -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -y outTest.mp4

Error:
[Parsed_overlay_cuda_10 @ 0x355b340] Timeline ('enable' option) not supported with filter 'overlay_cuda'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x2ebc880] Error initializing filter 'overlay_cuda' with args '515:80:enable=between(t,4,15)'
Error initializing complex filters.
Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome

Thank you in advance for any guidance you may have.

Comment: You have to add `hwdownload,format=nv12` before the fade, and `hwupload` after the setpts.

Comment: Thanks Gyan... but after altering  as suggested I get an error:      ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i vidTest.mp4 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i imgTest.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale_npp=960:540:format=yuv420p,hwdownload,hwupload_cuda,scale_npp=format=nv12[base];[1:v]scale_npp=470:-1,hwdownload,format=nv12,fade=st=0:d=2:alpha=1,fade=out:st=9:d=2:alpha=1,trim=0:15,setpts=PTS+4/TB,hwupload[A];[base][A]overlay_cuda=515:80:enable='between(t,4,15)'" -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -y outTest.mp4  .... Timeline ('enable' option) not supported with filter 'overlay_cuda'

Comment: Also Gyan... This is part of error too:  Error initializing filter 'overlay_cuda' with args '515:80:enable=between(t,4,15)'
Error initializing complex filters.
Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome